# Misbehaviour single click uploading image twice

Tags: android, android-volley

I have a button to find an image on gallery and a button to upload the image to the server.
The problem is, user clicks on it once and it send 2 requests to server, uploading 2 times. Any ideas whats is wrong? And how to solve?

```
//gallery and upload buttons:

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch (v.getId()) {
            case R.id.imageToUpload:

                if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
                    if (checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_DENIED) {
                        String[] permissions = {Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE};
                        requestPermissions(permissions, PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE);
                    }
                }

                Intent galleryIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
                startActivityForResult(galleryIntent, RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE);
                break;
            case R.id.bUploadImage:

                bUploadImage.setEnabled(false);

                Bitmap image = null;
                if(hasImage(imageToUpload)) {
                    image = ((BitmapDrawable) imageToUpload.getDrawable()).getBitmap();
                }
                else{
                    if(uploadImageName.length() < 2){ // no image and no text
                        bUploadImage.setEnabled(true);
                        return;
                    }
                }
                new UploadImage(image, uploadImageName.getText().toString());
                break;
        }
        super.onClick(v); //to baseactivity profile click work.
    }
```

and class to upload:

```
private class UploadImage {
    Bitmap image;
    String name;
    String encodedImage = "";

    UploadImage(Bitmap image, String name) {
        this.image = image;
        this.name = name;

        if(image != null) {
            ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            image.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, byteArrayOutputStream);
            encodedImage = Base64.encodeToString(byteArrayOutputStream.toByteArray(), Base64.DEFAULT);
        }

        Response.Listener<String> responseListener = new Response.Listener<String>(){

            @Override
            public void onResponse(String response){
                try {
                    JSONObject jsonResponse = new JSONObject(response);
                    boolean success = jsonResponse.getBoolean("success");
                    if(success){
                        String done = getResources().getString(R.string.done);
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), done, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                    else{
                        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(Upload.this);
                        String error = getResources().getString(R.string.error);
                        String retry = getResources().getString(R.string.retry);
                        builder.setMessage(error)
                                .setNegativeButton(retry,null)
                                .create()
                                .show();
                    }
                } catch (JSONException e){
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

        };

        UploadRequest uploadRequest = new UploadRequest(encodedImage, UserId, name, token, responseListener);
        RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(Upload.this);
        queue.add(uploadRequest);

    }
}
```

any ideas why it is sending the post 2 times to the server when user clicks on button once?

Comment: Do BaseActivity also handles a click with the same ID? it can be your source of error

Comment: @MarcosVasconcelos I have this on BaseActivity:     `@Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch(v.getId()) {
            case R.id.ProfilePicMenu:
                Intent intent = new Intent(this, Profile_Activity.class);
                this.startActivity(intent);
                break;
        }
    }`

Comment: So how you know its called twice? Is onResponse called two times? debug it

Comment: If you debug the constructor of UploadImage you can also check who calling it

Comment: it is sending a volley request to php, and always I get 2 uploads on db.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it can be solved trough debugging

Comment: If your code ins't called twice so your server is adding it

Comment: thank you friend. I'll learn how to debug.

Comment: Move the cursor (write) to the line you want to add a debug point and press Ctrl+ Shift+ F8, then press Shift+ F9 to start in debug, when the code reach that point it will stop

Comment: @MarcosVasconcelos thank you very much!